# loop through functions with multiple arguments from list python

Tags: python, list, pandas, for-loop

I have a function that takes two arguments together: `func(arg1, arg2)`

And I have a dataframe that has the arugment values:

```
df

0    col1    col2    col1+col2
1    A       B       A, B
2    C       D       C, D
3    E       F       E, F
```

I tried a for-loop where i stated:

```
results = [ func(i, j) for i, j in df['col1'] & df['col2'] ]
```

but that does not seem to work; are my variables in my for-loop not recognized in the stated columns?

Comment: are you missing a closing bracket?

Comment: `results = [func(i, j) for i, j in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]`

Comment: yes i was thank you, missed that one for this post

Comment: df['col1+col2']=df['col1']+','+df['col2']

Comment: that worked!! thank you COLDSPEED!